# Why don't System.out.printlin, and Logger work in my websocket?

Tags: websocket, server-side, wildfly-10, java.util.logging

Can anyone tell me why why nothing I log from my class, and nothing I print using System.out.println, shows up in the log or on the console?

My websocket endpoint class is named 
"org.america3.websockets.sockets.WSEndPoint"

I know it successfully deploys to Wildfly in a .WAR package (inside an .EAR package), because my html page confirms it that it opens a websocket object.

From my endpoint class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;    
@Transient 
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WSEndpoint.class);
```

In my standalone-full.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
...
  <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>
  ...
  <console-handler name="MY-CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="MY-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <target name="System.out"/>
  </console-handler>
  ...
  <console-handler name="TEST-HANDLER">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="TEST-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>
  ...
  <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
  </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
...
  <logger category="org.america3" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="ALL"/>
    <handlers>
      <handler name="TEST-HANDLER"/>
    </handlers>
  </logger>
...
  <root-logger>
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
      <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
  </root-logger>
...
  <formatter name="PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="MY-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="MeMeMe%s%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <formatter name="TEST-PATTERN">
   <pattern-formatter pattern="*** %s%n"/>
  </formatter>
...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: What is the package name of `WSEndpoint.class`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only answer, but it worked.

Originally I packaged my Endpoint in the same jar I used to deploy my Session beans. And made the jar a module of my ear package.  The Session Beans deployed and logged correctly. The Endpoint didn't.

Then I redeployed my endpoint under META-INF/classes of a war package as a second ear module, and it worked as it should.

I'm sure I read somewhere that an Endpoint could be deployed in the ear package along with other classes.  So I'm not sure if maybe I fixed some other error I didn't originally -- that was fixed when I repackaged the app.

But for now it works as it should, so I'll stay with keeping my Endpoint in the war META-INF/classes directory.